# Custom akka mail box configuration (Scala)

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I created my custom mailbox called `CustomMailBox` which derived from `MyUnboundedMessageQueueSemantics` trait. Then i put this configurations into application.conf:

```
custom-dispatcher {
  mailbox-requirement =
    "com.MyUnboundedMessageQueueSemantics"
}

akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {
  "com.MyUnboundedMessageQueueSemantics" =
    custom-dispatcher-mailbox
}

custom-dispatcher-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "com.CustomMailBox"
}

akka.actor.deployment {
  /myactor {
    dispatcher = custom-dispatcher
  }
}
```

After that i create my actor this way:

```
val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
val quadrocopter = system.actorOf(Quadrocopter.props(vrep, clientID, handler)
        .withDispatcher("custom-dispatcher"), "myactor")
```

and after running my program i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" akka.ConfigurationException: Dispatcher [custom-dispatcher] not configured for path akka://mySystem/user/myactor
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:758)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:273)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:46)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:374)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:732)
    at Simulation$.delayedEndpoint$Simulation$1(Simulation.scala:24)
    at Simulation$delayedInit$body.apply(Simulation.scala:12)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Simulation$.main(Simulation.scala:12)
    at Simulation.main(Simulation.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Can anybody explain me what is wrong in that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing `/myactor` to `" */myactor"` in config file.
Second step is to remove invocation of `withDispatcher()` function when creating actor.